# Unable to run springboot application with gradle bootrun

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-11

Creating springboot application and i am unable to run it.

Here is what my Application class looks like

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class ApplicationMain implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private CloudStorage cloudSt;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(ApplicationMain.class);
        app.run();
    }

    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("--------------");
        cloudSt.print();
    }
}
```

I run this application by using command `gradle bootRun` and it gives following output

```bash
❯ gradle bootRun

> Task :bootRun
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
4 actionable tasks: 4 executed
```

Note there is no error.

*Note*: I am building an app which would be used as `Jar` file but i am testing this as a commandline app to verify if the properties are being injected properly or not. for reference, here is my `CloudStorage` bean

```java
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "cloud.storage")
public class CloudStorage {
    @Value("${accountName}")
    private String accountName;

    @Value("${key}")
    private String key;

    @Value("${containerName}")
    private String containerName;

    public AzureBlobDirectory getAzureRootDirectory() throws CloudStorageException {
        try {
            CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(buildConnectionString(accountName, key));
            CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = cloudStorageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();
            return new AzureBlobDirectory(cloudBlobClient, containerName);
        } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
            throw new CloudStorageException(ex);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException ex) {
            throw new CloudStorageException(ex);
        }
    }

    private String buildConnectionString(String accountName, String accountKey){
        return String.format("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=%s;AccountKey=%s", accountName, accountKey);
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.printf("%s --- %s --- %s\n", accountName, key, containerName);
    }
}
```

- Am i configuring my springboot application wrong?
- What am i missing here, why i don't see the print statements from my main class

Comment: Can you share your `build.gradle` script? You appear to be missing a logging framework. In a Spring Boot application that's typically Logback and it should be on the classpath through a `spring-boot-starter-*` dependency

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I ended up adding `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter` to `implementation` group and it worked (it worked in the sense that it showed me other errors which was causing the issue) and i am able to solve them. 

you can put this as an answer so that i can acept

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be missing a logging framework that integrates with SLF4J:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
```

As a result, it has defaulted to a no-operation implementation which means that log messages will not be output anywhere:

```
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
```

In a Spring Boot application, the default logging framework that integrates with SLF4J is Logback. It should be on the classpath through a dependency on `spring-boot-starter` or `spring-boot-starter-*`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Slf4j` annotation.

```
@Component
@Slf4j
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "cloud.storage")
public class CloudStorage {
    @Value("${accountName}")
    private String accountName;

    @Value("${key}")
    private String key;

    @Value("${containerName}")
    private String containerName;

    public AzureBlobDirectory getAzureRootDirectory() throws CloudStorageException {
        try {
            CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(buildConnectionString(accountName, key));
            CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = cloudStorageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();
            return new AzureBlobDirectory(cloudBlobClient, containerName);
        } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
            log.error(ex.toString());
            throw new CloudStorageException(ex);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException ex) {
            log.error(ex.toString());
            throw new CloudStorageException(ex);
        }
    }

    private String buildConnectionString(String accountName, String accountKey){
        return String.format("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=%s;AccountKey=%s", accountName, accountKey);
    }

    public void print() {
        log.info("%s --- %s --- %s\n", accountName, key, containerName);
    }
}
```